# Implementing a timer to stop abuse in a socket IRC bot?

Tags: python, timer, irc, bots

Code:

```
while True:
    data = irc.recv(4096)
    if data.find('PING') != -1:
        irc.send('PONG '+ data.split() [1] +' \r\n')
    if data.find('!latest') != -1:
        irc.send('PRIVMSG #PwnMyI :\x02Latest Article:\x02 %s, \x02written by\x02 %s \r\n' % (art_name, art_auth))
        irc.send('PRIVMSG #PwnMyI :\x02Description:\x02 %s \r\n' % art_desc)
        irc.send('PRIVMSG #PwnMyI :\x02View Article:\x02 %s \r\n' % art_link)
```

This is a snippet of code from my bot. The rest of the code is custom build, and split into different files, and you don't need them anyway.

`irc` is the socket connection, and `send` sends the data over the socket. What I want to do is implement a timing feature, so that it'll only work once every 5 minutes. Just to stop abuse. Can anyone point me in the right direction? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a last sent timestamp variable.  When you post, check to see if the last sent timestamp is within a certain time period.  If it is, don't post.  If it isn't, post and update it with the current time.